# Unresponsive UI using background worker, processing files are very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, ocr, file-transfer

Unresponsive UI using background worker, processing files are very slow.
Two different issues encountered here. GDpicture SDK is used for image processing. CPU Utilization is bare minimum, how can I maximize performance, ultimately have responsive and fast wpf application.

namespace OCR
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window

```
{
    BackgroundWorker bw;/*= new BackgroundWorker();*/
    private SynchronizationContext threadSyn = null;

   string log_cap = string.Empty;
    List<string> log_list = new List<string>();
    

    string value = "Merged";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeBackgroundWorker();
            File_process();
            string configpath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"path.txt");
            string[] configfile = File.ReadAllLines(configpath);
            if (configfile.Length > 1)
            {
                ip.Text = configfile[0];
                op.Text = configfile[1];
                ex_tb.Text = configfile[2];
                Protb.Text = configfile[3];
            }               
            cbPDFConform.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetNames(typeof(PdfConformance)).Length - 1; i++)
            {
                ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
                cbi.Content = Enum.GetName(typeof(PdfConformance), (PdfConformance)i);
                PdfConformance test = (PdfConformance)i;
                cbi.Tag = (PdfConformance)i;
                cbPDFConform.Items.Add(cbi);
            }
            cbPDFConform.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cbProcessorCount.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i <= Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
            {
                cbProcessorCount.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                if (Environment.ProcessorCount / 2 == i) { cbProcessorCount.SelectedIndex = i - 1; }
            }
            LicenseManager oLicenseManager = new LicenseManager();
            oLicenseManager.RegisterKEY("");

            configpath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"path.txt");
            configfile = File.ReadAllLines(configpath);
            if (configfile.Length > 1)
            {
                ip.Text = configfile[0];
                op.Text = configfile[1];
                ex_tb.Text = configfile[2];
                Protb.Text = configfile[3];
            }
            GrantAccess(ip.Text);
            GrantAccess(op.Text);
            GrantAccess(ex_tb.Text);
            GrantAccess(Protb.Text);
            threadSyn = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }

        catch (Exception e1)
        { MessageBox.Show("e1" + e1.Message); }
    }

    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;           

    }             

    public async void File_process()
    {           
     await Task.Run(() => converttiffpdfreducer());               
    }

    private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {               
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"path.txt"), false))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(ip.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(op.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(ex_tb.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(Protb.Text);
                    sw.Close();
                }
                ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
                parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = int.Parse(cbProcessorCount.SelectedItem.ToString());
                var watch1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                watch1.Start();
                converttiffpdfreducer();
                //deletenew();
                watch1.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts1 = watch1.Elapsed;
                ts1.ToString("mm\\:ss");

                if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
                {
                    value = "OCRed";
                }
                WriteLn("All documents have been successfully " + value + " " + ts1 + " " + DateTime.Now +" "+Environment.UserName);                    
            }
            catch (Exception DOwork)
            { MessageBox.Show("e2 " + DOwork.Message); }
        });
    }
    private void GrantAccess(string fullPath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }
    private string[] mutliocr(string[] arr)
    {
        string box = string.Empty;
        string box1 = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string filepath = string.Empty;
            string outpath = ex_tb.Text;
            if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
            { filepath = op.Text; }
            else if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
            { filepath = Protb.Text; }
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            var watch2 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch2.Start();
            string[] getfilearray = arr;
            for (int f = 0; f < getfilearray.Length; f++)
            {
                string dirName = Directory.GetParent(getfilearray[f]).FullName;
                string folder = Directory.GetParent(getfilearray[f]).FullName;

                box = Path.GetDirectoryName(getfilearray[f]);
                box1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(box);
                string getextension = Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]);
                string[] newF = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
                string FN = Directory.GetParent(getfilearray[f]).Name;
                string ocrfolder = (new FileInfo(getfilearray[f]).Directory.FullName);
                string filen = Path.Combine(ocrfolder, folder, FN + "-ocr" + getextension);
                string dict = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Redist", "OCR");
                if (!Directory.Exists(ocrfolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ocrfolder);
                }
                GrantAccess(ocrfolder);
                GdPicturePDF oGdPicturePDF = new GdPicturePDF();
                oGdPicturePDF.OcrPagesDone += OcrPagesDone;
                void OcrPagesDone(GdPictureStatus status1)
                {
                    if (oGdPicturePDF.SaveToFile(filen) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                    { }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("PDF: The OCR-ed file has failed to save. Status: " + oGdPicturePDF.GetStat().ToString());
                }
                GdPictureStatus status = GdPictureStatus.OK;
                    if (oGdPicturePDF.LoadFromFile(getfilearray[f], false) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                        if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                        {
                            if (oGdPicturePDF.OcrPages_4("*", 0, "eng", dict, "", 300, OCRMode.FavorSpeed, 1, true) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                                if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                                { }
                                else
                                { MessageBox.Show("PDF: The OCR process has failed. Status: " + status.ToString()); }
                        }
                        else
                        { MessageBox.Show("PDF: The PDF file has failed to load. Status: " + status.ToString()); }
                    
                oGdPicturePDF.Dispose();
                GrantAccess(getfilearray[f]);
                File.Delete(getfilearray[f]);
                watch2.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts2 = watch2.Elapsed;
                ts2.ToString("mm\\:ss");                    
                    WriteLn(" OCR pages " + filen.Replace(op.Text, "") + " " + ts2 + " " + DateTime.Now);                        
                }               
            if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
            {
                foreach (string str in Directory.EnumerateFiles(op.Text, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray())
                {
                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).EndsWith("-ocr"))
                        File.Move(str, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(str), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Substring(0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Length - 4) + ".pdf"));
                }
            }
            if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
            {
                FileSystem.MoveDirectory(Protb.Text, op.Text, UIOption.AllDialogs);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Protb.Text);
                string FF = string.Empty;
                foreach (string str in Directory.EnumerateFiles(op.Text, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {

                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).EndsWith("-ocr"))
                        File.Move(str, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(str), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Substring(0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Length - 4) + ".pdf"));
                }
            }

            }));
        }
        catch (Exception mul)
        {              
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static string browseFolder()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        string path = string.Empty;
        if (result == (System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult)MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            path = fbd.SelectedPath;

            if (path[path.Length - 1] != '\\')
            {
                path = path + "\\";
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    private string[] converttiffpdfreducer()
    {
        string[] dir = null;
        string box = string.Empty;
        string box1 = string.Empty;
        string[] gg = null;
        try
        {
            string filepath = ip.Text;
            string outpath = Protb.Text;

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                PdfConformance optPDFConform = PdfConformance.Unknown;
                dir = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(filepath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(l => l.Length != 0).OrderBy(f => f).ToArray();
                for (int ad = 0; ad < dir.Length; ad++)
                {   string[] getfilearray = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir[ad], "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
                    if (getfilearray.Length == 0)
                        break;
                    if (getfilearray.Length != 0)
                        for (int f = 0; f < getfilearray.Length; f++)
                        {
                            string getext = Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]);
                            string fd = Path.GetDirectoryName(getfilearray[f]);
                            string op_path = fd.Replace(filepath, Protb.Text);
                            string getextension = Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]);
                            string dict = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Redist", "OCR");
                            string outputPath = fd.Replace(filepath, outpath);
                            string FNAME = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(getfilearray[f]);
                            string fn = Path.GetDirectoryName(getfilearray[f]).Replace(filepath, outpath);
                            string filen = Path.Combine(outputPath, fn, FNAME + ".pdf");
                            string savefile = Path.Combine(op_path, filen);

                            string pathString = getfilearray[f];
                            box = Path.GetDirectoryName(getfilearray[f]);
                            box1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(box);
                            using (GdPictureDocumentConverter oConverter = new GdPictureDocumentConverter()) {
                                GdPictureStatus status = new GdPictureStatus();
                                if (Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]).ToUpper() == ".PDF")
                                {
                                    status = oConverter.LoadFromFile(getfilearray[f], GdPicture14.DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatPDF);
                                }

                                else if (Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]).ToUpper() == ".TIF" || Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]).ToUpper() == ".TIFF")

                                {
                                    status = oConverter.LoadFromFile(getfilearray[f], GdPicture14.DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatTIFF);
                                }
                                else if (Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]).ToUpper() == ".JPG")
                                {
                                    status = oConverter.LoadFromFile(getfilearray[f], GdPicture14.DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatJPEG);
                                }

                                if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                                {
                                    if (!Directory.Exists(op_path))
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(op_path);
                                    }
                                    GrantAccess(op_path);
                                    optPDFConform = (PdfConformance)((ComboBoxItem)cbPDFConform.SelectedItem).Tag;
                                    status = oConverter.SaveAsPDF(savefile, optPDFConform);
                                    if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                                    { }
                                    else
                                    { }
                                }
                                else
                                { }
                            }
                        }
                    string BOXX = box.Replace(ip.Text, Protb.Text);
                    string[] Arr = Directory.EnumerateFiles(BOXX, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
                    if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
                    { merge(Arr); }
                    else if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
                    {
                        mutliocr(Arr);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        { }                        
        return dir;
    }

    private string[] merge(string[] arr)
    {
        string box = string.Empty;
        string box1 = string.Empty; string[] gg = null;           
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {                                     
            box = Path.GetDirectoryName(arr[0]);
            box1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(box);
            string dirName = Directory.GetParent(arr[0]).FullName;
            string BOXFILES = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirName);
            string folder = Directory.GetParent(arr[0]).FullName.Replace(Protb.Text, op.Text);              
           
            string ocrfolder = (new FileInfo(arr[0]).Directory.FullName).Replace(Protb.Text, op.Text);
            string fn = Directory.GetParent(arr[0]).Name;
            string filen = Path.Combine(ocrfolder, folder, fn + ".pdf");
            if (!Directory.Exists(ocrfolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ocrfolder);
            }
            GrantAccess(ocrfolder);
            using (GdPicturePDF oGdPicturePDF = new GdPicturePDF())
            {
                GdPictureStatus status = oGdPicturePDF.MergeDocuments(ref arr, filen);

                if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                { }
                else
                { }
                oGdPicturePDF.Dispose();
            }
        Directory.Delete(box, true);         
        string BOXX = box.Replace(Protb.Text, op.Text);//op            
        string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(BOXX, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
        if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
        { mutliocr(files); }            
        }));
        return gg;
    }

    private void inbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { ip.Text = browseFolder(); }
        catch (Exception e7)
        { MessageBox.Show("e7" + e7.Message); }
    }
    private void obtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { op.Text = browseFolder(); }
        catch (Exception e8)
        { MessageBox.Show("e8" + e8.Message); }
    }
    private void start_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!bw.IsBusy)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            this.bw.CancelAsync();

            // Disable the Cancel button.

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            start_btn.Content = "Stop";
            //this.Status.Content = "Running....";

        }
        else
        {
            bw.CancelAsync();
            start_btn.Content = "Start";
            //this.Status.Content = "Stopped....";

        }
    }
    private void pro_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { Protb.Text = browseFolder(); }
        catch (Exception e10)
        { MessageBox.Show("e10" + e10.Message); }
    }
    private void excep_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { ex_tb.Text = browseFolder(); }
        catch (Exception e11)
        { MessageBox.Show("e111" + e11.Message); }
    }      

    private void WriteLn(string text)
    {
        logtb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            logtb.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
        }));

        log_list.Add(text);
        log_cap = text + Environment.NewLine + log_cap;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"FileProcessing_log.txt"), false))
        {
            foreach (string l in log_list)
                sw.WriteLine(l);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is a lot of code here. You will need to make a [mcve], or risk this not being answered or closed

Comment: Marc and I posted pretty much the same answer at the same time. Using dispatcher.invoke to run everything from a background thread onto the ui thread makes the backgroundworker almost pointless. Additionally. You should develop iteratively. Write a bit of code and see what happens. You write a stack of code and now realised it's got a problem somewhere in that lot. Either you're not developing iteratively or you're not checking each part properly.

Comment: Your code has some flaws. For example calling `converttiffpdfreducer()` using `Task.Run` but the method itself is completely executed on the Dispatcher is waste of resources and does nothing to improve your performance. You have really posted too much code. Please identify the CPU intensive operations. Is it only `converttiffpdfreducer`?  `File_process` MUST return a Task and MUST be awaited. If  `File_process` executed the CPU bound long running operation it MUST not be called from the constructor! Please help to understand your code so that we can provide a proper fix for all the issues.

Comment: File.ReadAllLines executes synchnornously. There is an asynchronous API to read files. Also youshould not do this in the constructor.

Comment: Using the async API means you can eliminate the background worker. By the way, you should always avoid to move IO operations to a background thread.

Comment: The result of `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` should be used with and enumerator in order to benefit from the stream. For example it should be used with foreach. it should not be used with an index. This means you should not finalize the result of `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`.

Comment: All this fixes will significantly improve the performance.

Comment: Why did you chose to execute converttiffpdfreducer on the Dispatcher?

Comment: Which framework are you using, .NET Core?

Comment: In your Mainwindow constructopr you are reading from the "path.txt" file twice.

Comment: Please don't deface questions like that. I have rolled-back your question.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to push things off the UI thread. You *do* that, but then in `Bw_DoWork` you immediately push things *back* the UI thread, with `this.Dispatcher.Invoke`, which blocks the worker thread until the work **now running on the UI thread** completes.

Basically: remove that `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` call, and just run the code *on the worker*. If you need to touch the UI, then you'll need to be on the UI thread for those bits, but *only* those buts.

Likewise, I doubt that `mutliocr` should be using dispatch invoke, and it *certainly* shouldn't change the UI thread to being a background thread (`Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;`).

Comment: getting "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." when im calling multiocr from merge

Comment: @Acian indeed, you can't touch the UI from a worker - the UI has "thread affinity". You must gather any data you need from the UI *before* you start the worker code, and perform any UI updates *afterwards* - for example, by using Dispatcher.Invoke to push updates back the UI - either incrementally during the work, or as a bulk update at the end. Ultimately, you can't have your cake and eat it: if you want to use a background thread to free up the UI, that background thread must **leave the UI alone** (except for passing it indirect messages)

Comment: I really appreciate, your valuable guidance here, where can I actually get or store values from UI here in public async Task InitializeAsync().  understand need to have all UI data for worker thread to execute.

Comment: Currently the app is firing even without any UI inputs, so where can capture the UI data, here in public async Task InitializeAsync()

Comment: @Acian `ip.Text` looks like a UI touch to me; also note that `await`, by default, uses sync-context (when there is one): which pushes you back to the UI thread

Comment: There are other UI elements check box and combo box even before any selection is made, without even clicking on the start button the app is processing .

Comment: @Acian I'm not sure what your question is here; "don't touch the UI from a background worker" seems pretty clear to me; can you clarify?

Comment: There are other UI elements in my app that's check box and combo box even before any selection is made, My first question is where can I capture the UI selections?  Second question is "without even clicking on the start button, the app is processing"

Comment: @Acian well, that second part is a statement, not a question, but: your code *tells it* to start - `Application_Startup` calls `InitializeAsync`; if you don't want it to start: don't do that; start the work in a button-click, or similar; the idea being: in that button click, capture the things you need to know *while on the UI thread*, and *then* start something in the background; as a side note: `async void` is **almost always** a huge mistake; you could use `Task.Run` or similar to start a worker without needing to use `async void`, noting that the delegate can use captured values

Comment: Thanks for the helpful inputs, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very very smelly and ugly. You seem to follow absolutely no naming convention at all. Locals and class members are camelCase and PascalCase and some use no casing at all and others use underscores. You should really review you code carefully with many aspects in mind and clean it up. There are  some redundancies too.

A really bad habbit of yours is the excessive use of the `Dispatcher`. For example, you create a background thread and post the *complete!* work of this thread back to the `Dispatcher`/UI thread. A huge waste of resources and elimination of any multithreading benefit.
You don't want to put all your work on the `Dispatcher`. You want to offload CPU intensive eork to a background thread. You want to make use of asynchronous APIs where possible. Because you want to keep the UI responsive. `Dispatcher` means UI thread.

Some highly important points of interest

- `GrantAccess` implementation is a severe security violation of user rights. Don't modify access rules. Rather filter and ignore resources where the current user is not authorized for access. What is especially critical, is that you never revert the access rights to the original state.
- As a general rule: don't execute IO related code (e.g., database, HTTP streams, file IO) on a background thread. Use async APIs instead. Use threading only for CPU bound work (e.g. computations, conversions).
- `File` has an async API you should always use. For example `File.OpenRead` returns a `FileStream` which exposes a `FileStream.ReadAsnyc` member. if you need more convenience when handling files like read line by line, then wrap the `FileStream` into a `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` and use members like `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync`
- To avoid `Dispatcher` calls, pass the required UI values to the concurent methods as argument. Better use data binding (which won't eliminate the cross threading issues writing, but would make your code more readable and eliminates `Dispatcher` invocation to read the values). Take alook at the refactored `File_process` method below. It shows how to pass UI values as argument to the `converttiffpdfreducer` method which is then executed on a background thread.
- Consider to add cancellation support to to the longrunning `converttiffpdfreducer()`
- Avoid calling `ToArray` or `ToList` on an `IEnumerable`. Those methods are finalizers that immediately execute the originally deferred LINQ queries.
- Don't call `ToArray` or `ToList` on the result of `EnumerateFiles` and its likes. Those methods are used to improve performance as they return the filesystem objects item by item. This is especially important if you recursively iterate over the complete filesystem structure. If the filesystem tree is very deep and broad, calling `ToArray` will force the itereation to complete and then to return all results at once. `ToArray` on `EnumerateFiles` is like using `GetFiles`. You should review your complete code and refactor it properly. You always use *Enumerate*XYZ wrong!

> "The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
> use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
> before the whole collection is returned. When you use GetFiles, you
> must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
> access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
> directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient."

- Use data binding instead of directly accessing UI elements. This allows you to read the properties on the background thread without using the `Dispatcher`.
- Never execute long running operation from the constructor
- Never call async code from the constructor
- Always keep object instantiation cheep and fast and without hidden performance/resource costs
- Never catch `Exception`. Always catch a specialized exception type.
- Don't use empty catch blocks. Either handle the exception if you can or laet it crash your application to give you a chance to fix bugs. When you swallow exceptions bugs will silently creep into your application. You will have a really hard time to discover them. Logging exceptions is not considered handling - rethrow in such case.
- You don't have to close a resource explicitly if you declare the resource using the `using` statement. The implicit call to `Dispose` once the instruction pointer leaves the `using` scope will close the resource automatically.

Implementing all the suggestion will significantly speed up your application.

I have refactored only some of your code to show how to properly use async APIs and `Task.Run` instead of the `BackgroundWorker`. I have removed every `Dispatcher` invocation. Instead of direct access to UI elements in order to read their values from the background thread, I have extracted those values before invoking the concurent method and passed those prefetched values as method arguments. If you would use data  binding you could read the property values directly and therefore ommit the method parameters.

The `MainWindow` should be shown manually from *App.xaml.cs* to allow asynchronous and longrunning initialization of the instance. For this pattern let the class that requires such initialization implement a public `InitializeAsync` method that can be awaited from the caller's context. Alternatively use `Lazy<T>` to defer initialization when required e.g., when initialization is depending on explicit access to members.

Although the refactored code will significantly improve the applicatoin's performance, you will have do to do some important refactoring yourself (following the pattern of the already refactored code sections).
Take a look at

- `InitializeAsync` and `WriteLnAsync` to learn how to use the async file IO API.
- `converttiffpdfreducer` to learn how to use the `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories` methods properly in order to significantly improve the performance.
- `mutliocr`, `merge` and `converttiffpdfreducer` to learn how pass UI element values as argument in order to avoid `Dispatcher` invocations.
- `start_btn_Click` and `converttiffpdfreducer` to learn how to implemnent cancellation and to guard your API against calls during an uninitialized state

**App.xaml**

```
<Application Startup="Application_Startup">

</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
class App : Application
{
  private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    // Because InitializeAsync depends on UI elements,
    // we have to wait until the Ui is loaded.
    mainWindow.Loaded += OnMainWindowLoaded;

    // Either call Show() before initialization or after.
    // If before, ensure access to uninitialized members and resources is denied
    // e.g. by querying the MainWindow.IsInitialized property in public members and event handlers.
    mainWindow.Show();        
  }

  private async void OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    => await mainWindow.InitializeAsync();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }
  private bool IsBusy { get; set; }
  private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  }

  // Execute blocking initialization routines asynchronously
  public async Task InitializeAsync()
  {
    if (IsInitialized)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Will execute the intesive CPU bound work on a background thread.
    await File_process(Cancellationtoken.None);

    string configpath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"path.txt");
    // Use async API to read/write from/to files and other IO resources
    using (FileStream configfile = File.OpenRead(configpath))
    {
      using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(configfile))
      {
        var configFileContent = new List<string>();
        while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
        {
          string lineOfFile = await fileReader.ReadLineAsync();
          configFileContent.Add(lineOfFile);
        }

        if (configFileContent.Any())
        {
          ip.Text = configFileContent[0];
          GrantAccess(configFileContent[0]);

          op.Text = configFileContent[1];
          GrantAccess(configFileContent[1]);

          ex_tb.Text = configFileContent[2];
          GrantAccess(configFileContent[2]);

          Protb.Text = configFileContent[3];
          GrantAccess(configFileContent[3]);
        }
      }
    }

    cbPDFConform.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetNames(typeof(PdfConformance)).Length - 1; i++)
    {
      ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
      cbi.Content = Enum.GetName(typeof(PdfConformance), (PdfConformance)i);
      PdfConformance test = (PdfConformance)i;
      cbi.Tag = (PdfConformance)i;
      cbPDFConform.Items.Add(cbi);
    }

    cbPDFConform.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cbProcessorCount.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
    {
      cbProcessorCount.Items.Add(i.ToString());
      if (Environment.ProcessorCount / 2 == i) { cbProcessorCount.SelectedIndex = i - 1; }
    }

    LicenseManager oLicenseManager = new LicenseManager();
    oLicenseManager.RegisterKEY("");

    threadSyn = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    IsInitialiezd = true;
  }

  public async Task File_process(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    // Read UI values to avoid Dispatcher calls from the background thread
    string ipText = ip.Text;
    string protbText = Protb.Text;
    string opText = op.Text;

    // Execute the intesive CPU bound work on a background thread.
    await Task.Run(() => converttiffpdfreducer(ipText, protbText, opText, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
  }

private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  IsBusy = true;

  using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"path.txt"), false))
  {
    await sw.WriteLineAsync(ip.Text);
    await sw.WriteLineAsync(op.Text);
    await sw.WriteLineAsync(ex_tb.Text);
    await sw.WriteLineAsync(Protb.Text);
  }

  try
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var watch1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    watch1.Start();

    // Consider to add cancellation support to File_process 
    await File_process(cancellationToken);

    watch1.Stop();

    TimeSpan ts1 = watch1.Elapsed;
    ts1.ToString("mm\\:ss");

    if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
    {
      value = "OCRed";
    }

    await WriteLnAsync("All documents have been successfully " + value + " " + ts1 + " " + DateTime.Now + " " + Environment.UserName, cancellationToken);

    IsBusy = false;
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    IsBusy = false;
    throw;
  }
}

  private async Task WriteLnAsync(string text, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    logtb.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;

    log_list.Add(text);
    log_cap = text + Environment.NewLine + log_cap;
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"FileProcessing_log.txt"), false))
    {
      foreach (string l in log_list)
      {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(l);
      }
    }
  }

  private async void start_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsInitialized)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (IsBusy)
    {
      // Cancel the longrunning operation.
      this.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
    start_btn.Content = "Start";

    try
    {
      await DoWorkAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      CancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
      CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
  }

  private void converttiffpdfreducer(
    string ipText, 
    string protbText, 
    string opText, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    string[] dir = null;
    string box = string.Empty;
    string box1 = string.Empty;
    string[] gg = null;


    PdfConformance optPDFConform = PdfConformance.Unknown;

    foreach (var directoryPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(ipText, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(l => l.Length != 0))
    {
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

      foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
      {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        string getext = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string fd = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        string op_path = fd.Replace(ipText, protbText);
        string getextension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string dict = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Redist", "OCR");
        string outputPath = fd.Replace(ipText, protbText);
        string FNAME = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        string fn = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath).Replace(ipText, protbText);
        string filen = Path.Combine(outputPath, fn, FNAME + ".pdf");
        string savefile = Path.Combine(op_path, filen);

        box = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        box1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(box);
        using (GdPictureDocumentConverter oConverter = new GdPictureDocumentConverter())
        {
          GdPictureStatus status = new GdPictureStatus();
          if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".PDF")
          {
            status = oConverter.LoadFromFile(filePath, GdPicture14.DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatPDF);
          }

          else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".TIF" || Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".TIFF")

          {
            status = oConverter.LoadFromFile(filePath, GdPicture14.DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatTIFF);
          }
          else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".JPG")
          {
            status = oConverter.LoadFromFile(filePath, GdPicture14.DocumentFormat.DocumentFormatJPEG);
          }

          if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
          {
            if (!Directory.Exists(op_path))
            {
              Directory.CreateDirectory(op_path);
            }
            GrantAccess(op_path);
            optPDFConform = (PdfConformance)((ComboBoxItem)cbPDFConform.SelectedItem).Tag;
            status = oConverter.SaveAsPDF(savefile, optPDFConform);
            if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
            { }
            else
            { }
          }
          else
          { }
        }
      }
    }

    string BOXX = box.Replace(ipText, protbText);

    // TODO::Refactor 'merge' and replace 'ToArray' with 'foreach'
    string[] Arr = Directory.EnumerateFiles(BOXX, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
    if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
    { merge(Arr, protbText); }
    else if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
    {
      mutliocr(Arr);
    }
  }

  private string[] merge(string[] arr, string protbText, string opText)
  {
    string box = string.Empty;
    string box1 = string.Empty; string[] gg = null;
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
      box = Path.GetDirectoryName(arr[0]);
      box1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(box);
      string dirName = Directory.GetParent(arr[0]).FullName;
      string BOXFILES = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirName);
      string folder = Directory.GetParent(arr[0]).FullName.Replace(protbText, opText);

      string ocrfolder = (new FileInfo(arr[0]).Directory.FullName).Replace(protbText, opText);
      string fn = Directory.GetParent(arr[0]).Name;
      string filen = Path.Combine(ocrfolder, folder, fn + ".pdf");
      if (!Directory.Exists(ocrfolder))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ocrfolder);
      }
      GrantAccess(ocrfolder);
      using (GdPicturePDF oGdPicturePDF = new GdPicturePDF())
      {
        GdPictureStatus status = oGdPicturePDF.MergeDocuments(ref arr, filen);

        if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
        { }
        else
        { }
        oGdPicturePDF.Dispose();
      }
      Directory.Delete(box, true);
      string BOXX = box.Replace(protbText, opText);//op            
      string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(BOXX, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
      if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
      { mutliocr(files, protbText, opText); }
    }));
    return gg;
  }

  private string[] mutliocr(string[] arr, string protbText, string opText)
  {
    string box = string.Empty;
    string box1 = string.Empty;
    try
    {
      string filepath = string.Empty;
      if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
      { filepath = opText; }
      else if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
      { filepath = protbText; }
      System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
      {
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
        var watch2 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch2.Start();
        string[] getfilearray = arr;
        for (int f = 0; f < getfilearray.Length; f++)
        {
          string dirName = Directory.GetParent(getfilearray[f]).FullName;
          string folder = Directory.GetParent(getfilearray[f]).FullName;

          box = Path.GetDirectoryName(getfilearray[f]);
          box1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(box);
          string getextension = Path.GetExtension(getfilearray[f]);
          string[] newF = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
          string FN = Directory.GetParent(getfilearray[f]).Name;
          string ocrfolder = (new FileInfo(getfilearray[f]).Directory.FullName);
          string filen = Path.Combine(ocrfolder, folder, FN + "-ocr" + getextension);
          string dict = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Redist", "OCR");
          if (!Directory.Exists(ocrfolder))
          {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ocrfolder);
          }
          GrantAccess(ocrfolder);
          GdPicturePDF oGdPicturePDF = new GdPicturePDF();
          oGdPicturePDF.OcrPagesDone += OcrPagesDone;
          void OcrPagesDone(GdPictureStatus status1)
          {
            if (oGdPicturePDF.SaveToFile(filen) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
            { }
            else
              MessageBox.Show("PDF: The OCR-ed file has failed to save. Status: " + oGdPicturePDF.GetStat().ToString());
          }
          GdPictureStatus status = GdPictureStatus.OK;
          if (oGdPicturePDF.LoadFromFile(getfilearray[f], false) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
            if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
            {
              if (oGdPicturePDF.OcrPages_4("*", 0, "eng", dict, "", 300, OCRMode.FavorSpeed, 1, true) == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                if (status == GdPictureStatus.OK)
                { }
                else
                { MessageBox.Show("PDF: The OCR process has failed. Status: " + status.ToString()); }
            }
            else
            { MessageBox.Show("PDF: The PDF file has failed to load. Status: " + status.ToString()); }

          oGdPicturePDF.Dispose();
          GrantAccess(getfilearray[f]);
          File.Delete(getfilearray[f]);
          watch2.Stop();
          TimeSpan ts2 = watch2.Elapsed;
          ts2.ToString("mm\\:ss");
          WriteLn(" OCR pages " + filen.Replace(opText, "") + " " + ts2 + " " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        if (MergeChk.IsChecked == true)
        {
          foreach (string str in Directory.EnumerateFiles(opText, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray())
          {
            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).EndsWith("-ocr"))
              File.Move(str, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(str), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Substring(0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Length - 4) + ".pdf"));
          }
        }
        if (MergeChk.IsChecked == false)
        {
          FileSystem.MoveDirectory(protbText, opText, UIOption.AllDialogs);
          Directory.CreateDirectory(protbText);
          string FF = string.Empty;
          foreach (string str in Directory.EnumerateFiles(opText, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
          {

            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).EndsWith("-ocr"))
              File.Move(str, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(str), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Substring(0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str).Length - 4) + ".pdf"));
          }
        }

      }));
    }
    catch (Exception mul)
    {
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs I'm incorporating them in code, I understand I don't use standard naming conventions. Nobody ever reads my code, you must all be thinking, good Lord. So now I understand how that can be an issue. BionicCode greatly appreciate, painstakingly you have actually reviewed my entire code. That's a real feat in itself. I'm trying to get it to run.  Have to admit haven't used threading or background process earlier, that caused the chaotic code. Implemented using .NET Framework.

Comment: You are right, I'm pretty sure something like "Good Lord" came to everybodies mind, indeed. It will keep many people away fro sure. I really felt dirty after reading your code, no joke ;)  You should really follow the official C# [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). This helps others her on SO to read your code and it will help you too. Your code will look much cleaner and will be more pleasant to work with. You must read code to understand it or to find bugs or to refactor it. Try your best to make code easy to read.

Comment: Regarding threading: it is always a good idea to read some docs before implementing code randomly without knowing what you are doing. The topic is too complex as that such an approach would lead to anything but garbage. Understanding the basics is not optional-  it is mandatory (as you can see).

Comment: I hope the above code guides you into the right direction. I have updated the `DoWorkAsync` method. It was missing the `await` on the `WriteLineAsync` method calls. Also fixed missing reset of `IsBusy` on cancellation.

Comment: Also added cancellation to `converttiffpdfreducer` (two lines).

Comment: InitializeAsync() needs to be called in order to initialise the path value, if File_process is called then the application does not have values for enumerating  directories.

Comment: In the example InitializeAsync is called from App.xaml.cs in Application_Startup().

Comment: Yes i see that in App.xaml.cs is called, but await File_process(CancellationToken.None) is what gets executed first before the config data is initialized.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. It's what was called first in your example code, third line in the constructor. i just copied your code and move it to InitializedAsync.

Comment: In my original code, I  was trying to call converttiffpdfreducer from file process and  do_ work to see which will work better. My question now is where should I call InitializeAsync , also the code which captures user data and the main function converttiffpdfreducer that is my main function that initiates other functions respectively form which point should I call

Comment: Originally you were calling those methods from the constructor. I was showing a way to call longrunning and/or async methods after instantiation using the InitializeAsync method. The MainWindow is now instantiated in App.xaml.cs as you can see. Then after contsruction the InitializeAsync method is called. This is how you should do it if you require the code to be executed on/directly after construction - to initialize the instance properly allowing full async execution you can always follow this InitializeAsync pattern. Constructors can't execute async code.

Comment: To kick-off converttiffpdfreducer just call the public and awaitable `File_process` method like it is done in InitializeAsync and DoWorkAsync (which is invoked from the button's click handler): `await File_process();` This should improve how your applications behave during the conversion. Always call `await Fileprocess()`, don't call converttiffpdfreducer  directly.

Comment: I really appreciate, your valuable guidance here, where can I actually get or store values from UI here in public async Task InitializeAsync(). understand need to have all UI data for worker thread to execute. – 

 9 mins ago   
Currently the app is firing even without any UI inputs, so where can capture the UI data, here in public async Task InitializeAsync() –

Comment: I have not changed the flow. The execution order  is the same as in your code. In the constructor you first call File_process(). I only moved code out of the constructor to defer its invocation. Now instead of having converttiffpdfreducer accessing e.g.,  ip.Text, the method File_process does this before calling converttiffpdfreducer. It's to avoid crsoss threading exceptions as converttiffpdfreducer is executed on a background thread. I don't know what ip.Text is as you never showed it. i guess it's a TextBox.

Comment: When you call File_process like InitializeAsync does, the File_process collects the input and passes it to converttiffpdfreducer. Again, I have not changed the flow except of moving the constructor to InitializeAsync. So if something is not working properly then it wasn't working before. _"Currently the app is firing even without any UI inputs"_ - you would have to exaplin this further. Currently code is only executed on instance construction and on button clicked - exactly like in your original code.

Comment: The app is processing even before the start button is clicked, ip. Text is the text box path to input directory . Earlier I had all the UI elements on my constructor.

Comment: I have updated the code in App.xaml.cs. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a ton @BionicCode, greatly appreciate  your timely help. Your detailed guidance. Rewriting my full code. Will always incorporate these key points in my coding.  It works as intended, is responsive. Now I'm working on improving the speed.

Comment: To speed up you should use EnumerateFiles and EnumerateDirectories properly.

Comment: In converttiffpdfreducer at the bottom there is a EnumerateFiles.ToArray and in mutliocr() there are three of this calls. You must merege all this calls into a single foreach. You can't search the complte filesystem that often in a single operation. This takes too much time. Merge them into a single foreach: `foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles("path"))`. You will feel the speed. Goal: make your algorith use a single EnumerateFiles with a foreach (**no ToArray call)**.